# How can I fix the design for tha devices that have different sizes

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

My code and (Genymotion emulator) screenshots are in the below. The screens seem different with the same code. For instance `REGISTER` button on Galaxy S2 screen doesn't seem the same position with Galaxy S3 screen.

One of screenshots is from a `Galaxy S2` and the other one is from a `Galaxy S3`.

Is there any chance to fix the screen layout for the devices that have different sizes and resolutions?

### Edit

(I've replaced the former code and schreenshots)

```
export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image source={require('./image.png')} style={styles.topImage} resizeMode={'contain'} />
                <View style={styles.form}>
                    <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder={'Username'} />
                    <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder={'Password'} />
                    <RaisedButton
                        style={{marginTop: 16, alignSelf:'stretch' }}
                        text='LOGIN'
                        color={'accent'}
                        onPress={() => alert('Login has been pressed!')}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.lastContainer}>
                        <RaisedButton
                            style={{marginTop: 36, alignSelf:'stretch' }}
                            text='FORGOT PASSWORD'
                            onPress={() => alert('Forgot Password has been pressed!')}
                        />
                        <RaisedButton
                            style={{marginTop: 16, alignSelf:'stretch' }}
                            text='REGISTER'
                            color={'accent'}
                            onPress={() => alert('Register has been pressed!')}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

let styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: 10,
    },
    topImage: {
        flex: 0.4,
        height: null,
        width: null,
        marginLeft: 55,
        marginRight: 55,
    },
    form: {
        flex: 1
    },
    lastContainer: {
        marginTop: 25,
    },
    textInput: {
        fontSize: 16,
        lineHeight: 48,
    },
})
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-display. I personally use Display.height to adjust heights.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickKlitzke. I think that the flex prop of Flexbox should work like percentage in CSS. Am I wrong?

Comment: Not really, Its more like deciding how the free space will be distributed. I recommend watching flexbox.io.

Comment: You could do somethibg like <View style={height:Display.height}> <View style={flex:1} /> <YourControls /> </View> if you want to display your controls at the bottom

Comment: I give you reputation for the flexbox.io . Thank you again.

Comment: I could return that issue after about one and half months. Yes Patrick you were right. I have to use display height to fix the all controls in fact because of Virtual Keyboard. In my case I use React-Native dimensions api.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can pull buttons to the bottom of the screen with empty `<View>` with flex=1:

```
  <View style={{flex: 1}}></View> <!-- empty spacer view -->
  <View style={styles.lastContainer}>
    <RaisedButton
      style={{marginTop: 36, alignSelf:'stretch' }}
      text='FORGOT PASSWORD'
      onPress={() => alert('Forgot Password has been pressed!')}
    />
    <RaisedButton
      style={{marginTop: 16, alignSelf:'stretch' }}
      text='REGISTER'
      color={'accent'}
      onPress={() => alert('Register has been pressed!')}
    />
  </View>
```

Alternatively, you an have a look on [react-native-extended-stylesheet](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet) that allows to use percentage values in style.

Comment: You're right! Thanks. Additionally, to understand your awesome (which seems as a complete solution) library needs some time. Maybe next time..